# How to change the style of the pages title in a view?

Tags: views, theming

I've created a content type view using teasers. The titles are all H1s. How to change that to H3, for example?

Is this just a case of CCS?

Comment: Does the Format section on the view have the option of show set to "Content | Teaser"? If so are you opposed to setting it to Fields? If you set the view to pull the Fields in then on a per field basis you can override the html output to be a different html element.

Answer (score 0):

Open firebug to see what are the ancestors of the `h1`, there should be a name that contains the content type or view, you can easily set:

```
.WRAPPER-OF-CONTENT-TYPE h1{
    //here is your css style
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enabling `Display Suite` and `Display Suite Extras` allows you the ability to control each field output's element, class, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to views admin page, go to the field with the title to "Output settings" and choose another tag for the output